# Running feature extraction on region within a boundary

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-extraction, matlab-cvst, feature-selection

The image below shows a cow where the boundary has been detected using a combination of thresholding and subtracting a background from a 3D depth image.

My goal is to perform feature extraction on the area INSDIE the boundary. I have read the other questions and have struggled to implement the steps refereed to in similar questions. I do not want to extract the area in the boundary, I simply want to use it for feature extraction.

Please could someone offer a solution that is perhaps simpler? For example, is there a way to give the extractSURFFeatures the boundary coordinates from which to work within?

Below is my boundary code which recieves my processed thresholded image (BW1).

[image]

```
figure(1);
  imshow(ImageCell_int{i-269});
  %title('Outlines, from bwboundaries()'); axis square;
  hold on;
  boundaries = bwboundaries(BW1);   
  numberOfBoundaries = size(boundaries);
  for k = 1 : numberOfBoundaries
     thisBoundary = boundaries{k};
     plot(thisBoundary(:,2), thisBoundary(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 2);
  end
  hold off;
```

I would be extremely grateful for any assistance on this.

Comment: Is it a problem for you to extract the feature points of all the image and then delete the ones that are outside the boundary?

Comment: No and that is a very good idea, thank you. My thinking was to use only the area within the boundary to minimise the amount of processing. Can you help me get started with this? I am new to image processing with Matlab.

Comment: Start with finding the rectangular bounding box of the region, and extracting features there, just using MATLAB indexing to extract the rectangle.  Then throw away points outside the complex region.  Don't optimize beyond this until you know you need to.

Comment: Follow Peters approach. Triying to optimize it beyond may be more constly!

Comment: I agree. I may have come up with a solution using masks. Can either of you tell me how to sum two images together so that my mask hides the regions i am not interested in? The only approaches I can find involving blending the 2 images somehow. I would like to add them together so that only the 'hole' left behind remains. Is this possible?

Comment: You just need to multiply the two things together.  Given that your mask consists of zeroes and ones, you simply have to take this mask and multiply it by your original image to obtain a masked version where anything that is dark means that it was suppressed by the zeroes of the mask.

Comment: It works only partially...the obscured regions are a transparent yellow and are still detected by the SURF detector.

Comment: @Adam893 Why don't you use [`extractFeatures`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extractfeatures.html#inputarg_points) function and give your boundary points (or whichever points you wish), as input. Am I missing something here? There are different features such as BRISK, SURF, FAST, HARRIS etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great, now I see the cow! :)

You cannot specify an irregularly-shaped region of interest for the `detectSURFFeatures` function. However, you can detect the features in the whole image, and then create a binary mask of the region of interest, and use it to exclude keypoints, which are outside it.

**Edit:** If your boundary is represented as a polygon, you can use `roipoly` function to create a binary mask from it.

Having said that, features that are outside your object's boundary can actually be useful, because they capture information about the shape of the object.

Also, what is your final goal?  If you want to recognize individual cows, then local features may not be the best approach. You may do better with a global HOG descriptor (`extractHOGFeatures`) or with a color histogram, or both.

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Can you please explain how to do the masking? I have had no luck getting a mask to work so far.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was discovered on Matlab Central and completely solves the problem above for anyone struggling with a similar issue.

Start with a grey scale outline of the object of interest (BW1).

```
    % Make the mask black and white
    double(BW1);
    BW2 = logical(BW1);
```

Next the mask is created and forced to be the same size as the normal image.

```
    mask = cast(BW2, class(normalImage));
    maskedImage = normalImage .* mask;

    imshow(maskedImage);
```

Yields the following result:

It is now possible to perform feature extraction on the object of interest.

[image]